# PHP files are downloaded by browser instead of processed by apache2 after creating virtual hosts

Tags: linux, apache, http, ubuntu-12.04, lamp

I created a virtual host in apache2 (LAMP) as shown below and the php files are downloaded by the browser instead of processed by apache. I created an HTML file and it worked.

/var/www/myvirtualhost.com/public_html

```
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost.com

DocumentRoot /var/www/myvirtualhost/public_html/

 ServerName myvistualhost
```

Answer (score 1):

Check [this question out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6245895/apache2-on-ubuntu-php-files-downloading). It's for Apache on Ubuntu, and you don't specify what system you are on, but maybe you can get a tip from there.

Basically it describe how to install the PHP module for Apache, which is probably not installed if PHP-files are downloaded.