# New wordpress site forces me to download index.php

Tags: php, wordpress, apache

I'm setting up a Wordpress site on my VPS and currently when I try to visit the website's root URL I am forced to download the contents of `index.php` (instead of having the php file be executed).

I suspect the problem may be with my `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/foobar.com.conf`:

```
SuexecUserGroup "#1007" "#1007"
ServerName foobar.com
ServerAlias www.foobar.com
ServerAlias webmail.foobar.com
ServerAlias admin.foobar.com
DocumentRoot /home/foobar/www
ErrorLog /var/log/virtualmin/foobar.com_error_log
CustomLog /var/log/virtualmin/foobar.com_access_log combined
ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /home/foobar/cgi-bin/
ScriptAlias /awstats/ /home/foobar/cgi-bin/
AddType application/x-httpd-php .html .htm
DirectoryIndex index.php
<Directory /home/foobar/public_html>
Options -Indexes +IncludesNOEXEC +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch +ExecCGI
allow from all
AllowOverride All Options=ExecCGI,Includes,IncludesNOEXEC,Indexes,MultiViews,SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
AddHandler fcgid-script .php
AddHandler fcgid-script .php5
FCGIWrapper /home/foobar/fcgi-bin/php5.fcgi .php
FCGIWrapper /home/foobar/fcgi-bin/php5.fcgi .php5
</Directory>
<Directory /home/foobar/cgi-bin>
allow from all
AllowOverride All Options=ExecCGI,Includes,IncludesNOEXEC,Indexes,MultiViews,SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
</Directory>
<Directory /home/foobar/www>
allow from all
AllowOverride All Options=ExecCGI,Includes,IncludesNOEXEC,Indexes,MultiViews,SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
</Directory>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =webmail.foobar.com
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://foobar.com:20000/ [R]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =admin.foobar.com
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://foobar.com:10000/ [R]
RemoveHandler .php
RemoveHandler .php5
php_admin_value engine Off
IPCCommTimeout 31
FcgidMaxRequestLen 1073741824
<Files awstats.pl>
AuthName "michaelarchinal.com statistics"
AuthType Basic
AuthUserFile /home/foobar/.awstats-htpasswd
require valid-user
</Files>
RedirectMatch /cgi-bin/mailman/([^/\.]*)(.cgi)?(.*) http://foobar.com:10000/virtualmin-mailman/unauthenticated/$1.cgi$3
RedirectMatch /mailman/([^/\.]*)(.cgi)?(.*) http://foobar.com:10000/virtualmin-mailman/unauthenticated/$1.cgi$3
Alias /pipermail /var/lib/mailman/archives/public
```

(**Note**: The url is not actually www.foobar.com - I've changed it to that for the sake of example)

Comment: possible duplicate of [apache2 on ubuntu - php files downloading](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6245895/apache2-on-ubuntu-php-files-downloading)

Comment: Are you sure your Apache server is running? Can you create a folder outside the one you have installed wordpress with another index.php file and open it?